# Average of additive character sum over all polynomials of degree at most $d$ over $GF(q)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, analytic-number-theory, characters, exponential-sum

Let $F$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, let $E$ be its degree $n \geq 2$ extension and let $\psi$ be the canonical additive character of $E$. For $d \leq n $ let 
$$
\mathcal{P}_{\leq d} = \{f(x) \in F[x] \ : \ \deg(f(x)) \leq d \text{ and } f(0) = 0\}.
$$
Note that $|\mathcal{P}_{\leq d}| = q^{d}$. For $f(x) \in F[x]$ let
$$
S(f) = \sum_{y \in E} \psi(f(y)).
$$

Do you know what are good bounds for the modulus of the average of the character sums
$$
A_d = \dfrac{1}{q^{d}} \sum_{f(x) \in \mathcal{P}_{\leq d}} S(f)?
$$
Of course the Weil bound may be applied here to each polynomial to get a bound. But I wonder if when we average over all such polynomials we can get better bounds than these?

Additionally, can we get better bounds if we restrict the monomials in each $f(x)$ above to induce permutations of $E$? Thanks.

Comment: If $q=p^n$ is odd, then we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}S(f(x)+j)=0$$ and consequently we see that $A_d=0$. If $p=2$, then this argument fails because $\psi(0)=\psi(1)=1$. I think we still get zero more often than not. I try to find a clean argument when I'm less tired.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki. This made me realize that we should either remove the polynomials $f(x) \in \mathcal{P}_{\leq d}$ with $f(0) = 0$. Or remove all those with $f(0) \neq 0$ and leave those with $f(0) = 0$. Otherwise using the orthogonality relation on the constant coefficients gives an easy $A_d = 0$ when $\gcd(n,q-1) = 1$. I'll fix the post so that these polynomials satisfy $f(0) = 0$ (but it is equivalent to only consider those with $f(0) \neq 0 $ instead when $\gcd(n,q-1)$)

Comment: BTW I noticed this http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/finitefields-F13/polycharsum.pdf

Comment: See the section "Mordell's bound" which seems related. Although the average there is taken over all the polynomials of degree at most $d$ but with coefficients in $E$, not the ones in $F[x]$ as I have above. But perhaps there is a way to tackle this case too with a similar technique?